# What will happen if I update the running app using SKStoreProductViewController?

Tags: ios, storekit

I have requirement to show update notice if user use old version of the app and need to update it (force update). So I make blocking dialog that cannot be dismissed and put 1 button to redirect the app to open app store

And recently I just discover that I can use `SKStoreProductViewController` to open app store page on the app. The main question, what will happened if user press update on the app store page to update the running app (updating himself)

Does the app will be closed immediately? or what will happened then?

Comment: Yes, once the download is triggered, the app will terminate so that it can be downloaded and updated. The user will need to launch the app again manually once the update is complete

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11. How did you confirm this? is there an official resource that mentions it or is this anecdotal? (i can't find anything in the docs)

Comment: Just observation of what happens to a running app when you initiate an update